# Javascript object blanking when getting to end of loops

Tags: javascript

I am running the following Javascript with a csv and I am attempting to put the whole thing into an array of objects.  I am building up the objects in 'spellNumbers' and then using assign() to add them to the 'spells' array. It all seems to go well until the end.  When the program drops out of the nested loops and I try to print the 'spells' array, it is empty.

I am just learning about js objects.

```js
const NO_OF_BOOKS = 7;
const NO_OF_SPELL_TYPES = 8;
const NO_OF_HOUSES = 4;
const SPELL_NAME = 7;
const HOUSE_NAME = 8;
const SPELL_TYPE_POS = 7;

var spells = [];
var spellNumbers = [];
d3.csv('./heatmap.csv', function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(d, i) {
        spellNumbers = [];
        spellNumbers[Object.values(d)[SPELL_TYPE_POS]] = {};
        //... and each book...
        for (var BookCnt =0; BookCnt < NO_OF_BOOKS; BookCnt++) {
        // Get the name of the spell type and
            x = parseInt(Object.values(d)[BookCnt]);

            // Use it to add an associative array element of the form:
            // spellNumbers['SpellType']['book']
            spellNumbers[Object.values(d)[SPELL_TYPE_POS]]
                        [Object.keys(d)[BookCnt]] = x;
        }
        temp = Object.assign({}, spellNumbers);
        if(d.House == "Gryffindor") {
            spells.push(temp);
        }
    });
});

console.log("Here is spells: ")
console.log(spells);
```

The csv looks like the following

```
Sorcerer's Stone    Chamber of Secrets  Prisoner of Azkaban Goblet of Fire  Order of the Phoenix    Half Blood Prince   Deathly Hallows SpellType   House
13  5   9   54  27  37  75  Charm   Gryffindor
24  23  3   38  35  22  98  Healing Spell   Gryffindor
5   6   17  16  23  19  36  Hex Gryffindor
3   34  5   74  56  68  105 Counter Spell   Gryffindor
17  12  12  29  20  42  67  Jinx    Gryffindor
1   3   25  9   40  39  42  Curse   Gryffindor
12  23  25  19  45  23  59  Transfiguration Gryffindor
7   6   20  41  31  25  62  Conjuration Gryffindor
17  12  33  54  29  48  23  Charm   Hufflepuff
13  10  17  30  7   41  38  Healing Spell   Hufflepuff
5   4   21  29  22  29  2   Hex Hufflepuff
```

Why is my object disappearing and what can I do to get it back?

Answer (score 1):

`d3.csv` is asynchronous. Therefore, the callback is executed and array *spells* is filled **after** you log it. Put the console.log inside `d3.csv`'s callback. There you can access the data.

If you need that data to proceed, you might want to create another function that get's called at the end of `d3.csv` and pass *spells* to it.

Answer (score 0):

The function inside d3.csv is not executed in order but asynchronous. Therefore, your console.log in the end is executed first and the array is filled after. You can prove it by putting console.logs into the function above.

A solution might be, to add a new function and call it from the end of d3.csv. Like this:

```
        // ...more code
        temp = Object.assign({}, spellNumbers);
        if(d.House == "Gryffindor") {
            spells.push(temp);
        }
    });

    calledOnFinish();
});
```